# How do I include several geolocations on one record via algolia-rails gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, algolia

According to [this](https://blog.algolia.com/geo-search-on-steroid/) blog post, Algolia now allows several geolocations on a single record. All we have to do is to pass it as an array. I've tried it with the [algolia-rails](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-rails) gem but was unable to do it.

Here are the combinations I've tried that does not work:

```
"geoloc": [
   {"lat": :latitude, "lng": :longitude}
]

geoloc [{:latitude, :longitude}]
```

And a bunch of other combinations. Most of it results in an error indicating that geoloc is expecting 2 arguments instead of 1 which is an array.

My original code for a single geoloc which works is:

```
geoloc :latitude, :longitude
```

Comment: The rails code looks like it it has only one geoloc. What happens when you call the same method multiple times?

https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-rails/blob/2d63c37ed6151e314e5479e6a102d1f48e23cd4f/lib/algoliasearch-rails.rb#L204-L209

Comment: Well that sucks :( Is there any way that I can do it via pure ruby?

Comment: can you see what happens when you call it multiple times?

Comment: Oh! Smart! Let me try that. I looked at their ruby gem and it seems to provide that functionality. I just need to know how to integrate that with the rails gem as well.

Comment: I called it multiple times and it does not seem to work. I still only see one geoloc on my index.

Comment: try using `add_attribute` method . See how tags accepts multiple - https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-rails/blob/2d63c37ed6151e314e5479e6a102d1f48e23cd4f/lib/algoliasearch-rails.rb#L204-L217

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133408/discussion-between-okysabeni-and-sairam).

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is:

```
def _geoloc
  [{ lat: x_1, lng: y_1 }, { lat: x_2, lng: y_2 }]
end

algoliasearch do
  attributes :_geoloc
end
```

This does the trick.

Comment: @okysabeni : if the answer is OK, can you mark it as accepted?